# An example of a quotient group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

So this is my first time calculating quotient groups.

The goal is to find the order of the factor group

$$
(\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2)/\langle(2,1)\rangle.
$$

Well, $\langle(2,1)\rangle=\lbrace (0,0),(0,1),(2,0),(2,1)\rbrace$, and since all the possible cosets in a group generates a partition, it is not difficult to realize that there are only $2$ cosets, so this should be the order of the factor group.

HOWEVER, the book answer says that the factor group has $8/2=4$ elements. How can this be? By the way, it says that $\langle(2,1)\rangle$ has $2$ elements...

Comment: Check your calculation. $\langle(2,1)\rangle=\{(2,1),(0,0)\}$

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2252561/finding-cosets-of-mathbbz-2-times-mathbbz-4-langle-1-2-rangle?rq=1).

Comment: $\langle(2,1)\rangle\neq \langle(2,0),(0,1)\rangle$

Comment: Oh my... I did a highscool error